# Limit without using Heine or L'Hôpital

Tags: analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to find the $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{e}-1)$ ? I can't use Heine theorem neither L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

$$
\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}-0}
$$
for $f$ defined as $f(x)=e^x$. Does the above form ring a bell? Something like $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ should.

Comment: Nice! ${}{{]{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt[n]e = e^{\frac1n} = 1 + \frac1n + o\left(\frac1{n}\right)$$

So $n (\sqrt[n] e-1) = 1 + o(1) \to 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the expression as $\;\dfrac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac1n}-\mathrm e^0}{\dfrac1n}$, a rate of variation of the exponential function from $0$. hence the limit is the derivative  of $\mathrm e^x$ at $x=0$, i.e. $1$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
to get
$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)
$
where $a > 0$,
this is

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(e^{\ln a/n}-1)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1+\ln a/n+O(1/n^2)-1)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln a+O(1/n)\\
&=\ln a\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Or, without Taylor expansions, as the derivative of $f(x) = a^x$ at $0$.